# An owner of a large amount of land?

Tags: single-word-requests, agriculture

Is there a word, or a term, for a person who owns a large amount of land? "large" in the sense of "enough that the person would need to employ people not in his family to cultivate it".

This would be a sort of an English equivalent of "Kulak" in (post-1917 vernacular) Russian or "Latifundista" in Castillian.

Note: The word or term must specifically exclude *small* land-owners, people who cultivate their own land.

Answer (score 2):

A ***[landowner](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/italiano-inglese/proprietario-terriero) :***

> is a person who owns land, especially a large amount of land.
>
> - ...rural communities involved in conflicts with large landowners.

(Collins)

You also have [latifundist,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22latifundist%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) but it is not a common  term.

Comment: That doesn't exclude people who cultivate their own land. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @einpoklum - I think “large landowner” is the expression you are looking for. Latifundist is a less common alternative.

Comment: @einpoklum sure, literally 'landowner' is 'someone who owns land' presumably of any size. But pragmatically, it is usually applied to someone who owns an estate and rents out the land to farmers, someone usually considered of a higher social class..

Answer (score 1):

OED

> **gentleman-farmer**, n.
>
> **A country gentleman engaged in farming, usually on his own estate; a farmer who holds a better social position than the generality of his class.**
>
> 1802   Edinb. Rev. 1 111   *The scarcity was produced by the higher order of farmers, whom he calls Gentlemen-farmers.*
>
> 1864   C. Knight Passages Working Life I. i. 19   *The ‘yeoman’ of those days..would now be recognised as ‘gentleman-farmer’.*

Comment: I didn't say the owner actually does any farming himself... also, "better" does not necessarily mean having as much land as I described. But still, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Originally suggested: The word would be Baron.

Baron implies the person has land and employs people to manage the land. 
A Baron is also known as Lord of the Manor. A manor is a large piece of land.

“... John Selden in his esteemed work Titles of Honour (1672) writes, "The word Baro (Latin for Baron) hath been also so much communicated, that not only all Lords of Manors have been from ancient time, and are at this day called sometimes Barons ...”

Refer:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_manor

Edit 1: The word would be baron. 
Refer: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baron

Comment: A Baron is a title of nobility. I don't mean to imply nobility.

Comment: @einpoklum - "Land baron" is used fairly often in the US, even though there is no (official) "nobility".

Comment: @einpoklum: here is an alternate definition of baron from MWd: : a man who possesses great power or influence in some field of activity
// a cattle baron

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baron

Comment: In your question you have emphasised to exclude “small”. A baron would never be considered “small”. There could be “small” landowners.

Comment: @sharken I looked at MW. The definitions for **baron** do not seem to include the idea expressed by the OP, which is that of 'a kulak.' *1a : one of a class of tenants holding his rights and title by military or other honorable service directly from a feudal superior (such as a king) 1b : a lord of the realm : noble, peer 2a : a member of the lowest grade of the peerage in Great Britain.* 1a is excluded as the manner in which the land is held is irrelevant, although usually it was owned. 1b is excluded as it requires nobility and does not include farming. 2a is thus likewise excluded.

Answer (score -2):

Not as general as it could be, but how about **planter**? From M-W:

> **[planter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/planter)**: one who owns or operates a plantation
>
> **[plantation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plantation)**: an agricultural estate usually worked by resident labor

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantation):

> A plantation is a large-scale estate meant for farming that
> specializes in cash crops. The crops that are grown include cotton,
> coffee, tea, cocoa, sugar cane, opium, sisal, oil seeds, oil palms,
> fruits, rubber trees and forest trees.
>
> Among the earliest examples of plantations were the latifundia of the
> Roman Empire, which produced large quantities of wine and olive oil
> for export. Plantation agriculture grew rapidly with the increase in
> international trade and the development of a worldwide economy that
> followed the expansion of European colonial empires. Like every
> economic activity, it has changed over time.

And also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantation_complexes_in_the_Southern_United_States) regarding plantations in the southern U.S.:

> A plantation complex in the Southern United States is the built
> environment (or complex) that was common on agricultural plantations
> in the American South from the 17th into the 20th century. The complex
> included everything from the main residence down to the pens for
> livestock. Southern plantations were generally self-sufficient
> settlements that relied on the forced labor of slaves, similar to the
> way that a medieval manorial estate relied upon the forced labor of
> serfs.
>
> Plantations are an important aspect of the History of the
> Southern United States, particularly the antebellum era (pre-American
> Civil War) era. The mild temperate climate, plentiful rainfall, and
> fertile soils of the southeastern United States allowed the
> flourishing of large plantations, where large numbers of enslaved
> Africans were held captive as slave labor and forced to produce crops
> to create wealth for a white elite.
>
> Today, as was also true in the
> past, there is a wide range of opinion as to what differentiated a
> plantation from a farm. Typically, the focus of a farm was subsistence
> agriculture. In contrast, the primary focus of a plantation was the
> production of cash crops, with enough staple food crops produced to
> feed the population of the estate and the livestock. A common
> definition of what constituted a plantation is that it typically had
> 500 to 1,000 acres (2.0 to 4.0 km2) or more of land and produced one
> or two cash crops for sale. Other scholars have attempted to define
> it by the number of slaves that were owned.

Comment: Interesting. Although - won't people mistake this term for someone who is literally employed in planting plants in the ground?

Comment: @einpoklum I thought you'd find it interesting. Confusion is possible for any word that has multiple meanings, but *planter* is the term for one who owns or manages a plantation, which is a large-scale estate whose cultivation requires large numbers of non-family members. I'm sure you noticed the references to latifundia and medieval manorial estates.